# Spring Security (annotations) wrong setup

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I need some help (I'm desperate) on how to setup a simple login database security. My login works, at least the part when I check user and password, problem is the roles and url mapping constraints. After I login with a valid user my roles are lost, I cannot access anything what is suposed to be for example the directory /secured/user/home.html it gives me 503 denied, admin neither.

Trying to setup this project since yesterday without any success. This is a rest spring mvc with angular login, need some help on how to logout correctly because it doesn't works.

my code snippet

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        .exceptionHandling().and()
        .anonymous().and()
        .servletApi().and()
        .headers().cacheControl().and()
        .authorizeRequests()

        //allow anonymous resource requests
        .antMatchers("/index.html").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/favicon.ico").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()

        //allow anonymous POSTs to login
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/login").permitAll()
        // Login page
        .antMatchers("/login.html").permitAll()
        //allow anonymous GETs to API
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/users/current").permitAll()
        // api/users/logout
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/users/logout").permitAll()
        //defined Admin only API area
        .antMatchers("/secured/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
        // user area
        .antMatchers("/secured/user/**").hasRole("USER")
        .antMatchers("/api/blognews/**").hasRole("USER")

        //all other request need to be authenticated
        .anyRequest().hasRole("USER").and()

        // custom JSON based authentication by POST of {"username":"<name>","password":"<password>"} which sets the token header upon authentication
        .addFilterBefore(new StatelessLoginFilter("/api/login", tokenAuthenticationService, userDetailsService, authenticationManager()), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)

        // custom Token based authentication based on the header previously given to the client
        .addFilterBefore(new StatelessAuthenticationFilter(tokenAuthenticationService), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
```

this project was based on postgres, hibernate, spring security and some simple rest services. my objective is a token login auth without use of cookies or session. almost there, but it had been a pain and almost drop on this.

My setup is using maven I upload the project here.

https://github.com/jbarros35/angular/tree/auth/businessdata

Execution log:

```
08:45:32.555 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/api/users/current'; against '/resources/**'
08:45:32.555 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /api/users/current at position 1 of 7 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
08:45:32.555 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /api/users/current at position 2 of 7 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'StatelessLoginFilter'
08:45:32.555 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /api/users/current at position 3 of 7 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'StatelessAuthenticationFilter'
08:45:32.570 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /api/users/current at position 4 of 7 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
08:45:32.570 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /api/users/current at position 5 of 7 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
08:45:32.570 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter - SecurityContextHolder not populated with anonymous token, as it already contained: 'com.businessdata.security.UserAuthentication@74e7e622'
08:45:32.570 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /api/users/current at position 6 of 7 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
08:45:32.570 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /api/users/current at position 7 of 7 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
08:45:32.570 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/api/users/current'; against '/index.html'
08:45:32.570 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/api/users/current'; against '/favicon.ico'
08:45:32.570 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/api/users/current'; against '/resources/**'
08:45:32.570 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Request 'GET /api/users/current' doesn't match 'POST /api/login
08:45:32.570 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/api/users/current'; against '/login.html'
08:45:32.570 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/api/users/current'; against '/api/users/current'
08:45:32.570 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /api/users/current; Attributes: [permitAll]
08:45:32.570 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Previously Authenticated: com.businessdata.security.UserAuthentication@74e7e622
08:45:32.571 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DEBUG o.s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased - Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@6e34ba4a, returned: 1
08:45:32.571 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Authorization successful
08:45:32.571 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor - RunAsManager did not change Authentication object
08:45:32.571 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /api/users/current reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
08:45:32.571 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher' processing GET request for [/businessdata/api/users/current]
08:45:32.571 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Looking up handler method for path /api/users/current
08:45:32.571 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Returning handler method [public com.businessdata.model.UserData com.businessdata.controller.UserController.getCurrent() throws java.lang.Exception]
08:45:32.571 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'userController'
08:45:32.572 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Last-Modified value for [/businessdata/api/users/current] is: -1
08:45:32.572 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DEBUG o.s.w.s.mvc.WebContentInterceptor - Looking up cache seconds for [/api/users/current]
08:45:32.572 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DEBUG o.s.w.s.mvc.WebContentInterceptor - Applying default cache seconds to [/api/users/current]
08:45:32.574 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.ResponseBodyAdviceChain - Invoking ResponseBodyAdvice chain for body=UserData: user
08:45:32.574 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.ResponseBodyAdviceChain - After ResponseBodyAdvice chain body=UserData: user
08:45:32.576 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor - Written [UserData: user] as "application/json;charset=UTF-8" using [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter@45de7b45]
08:45:32.576 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
08:45:32.576 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Successfully completed request
08:45:32.576 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter - Chain processed normally
08:45:33.401 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/secured/admin/home.html'; against '/resources/**'
08:45:33.401 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /secured/admin/home.html at position 1 of 7 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
08:45:33.401 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /secured/admin/home.html at position 2 of 7 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'StatelessLoginFilter'
08:45:33.401 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /secured/admin/home.html at position 3 of 7 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'StatelessAuthenticationFilter'
08:45:33.401 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /secured/admin/home.html at position 4 of 7 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
08:45:33.401 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /secured/admin/home.html at position 5 of 7 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
08:45:33.401 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter - Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@90572420: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@255f8: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: 21113D956870C796E52C273FBFD2B651; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
08:45:33.401 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /secured/admin/home.html at position 6 of 7 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
08:45:33.401 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /secured/admin/home.html at position 7 of 7 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
08:45:33.401 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/secured/admin/home.html'; against '/index.html'
08:45:33.401 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/secured/admin/home.html'; against '/favicon.ico'
08:45:33.401 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/secured/admin/home.html'; against '/resources/**'
08:45:33.401 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Request 'GET /secured/admin/home.html' doesn't match 'POST /api/login
08:45:33.401 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/secured/admin/home.html'; against '/login.html'
08:45:33.401 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/secured/admin/home.html'; against '/api/users/current'
08:45:33.401 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/secured/admin/home.html'; against '/api/users/logout'
08:45:33.401 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/secured/admin/home.html'; against '/secured/admin/**'
08:45:33.401 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /secured/admin/home.html; Attributes: [hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')]
08:45:33.401 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@90572420: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@255f8: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: 21113D956870C796E52C273FBFD2B651; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
08:45:33.401 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DEBUG o.s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased - Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@6e34ba4a, returned: -1
08:45:33.401 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter - Access is denied (user is anonymous); redirecting to authentication entry point
```

Comment: If you don't have access you don't have the role. Make sure the user has `ROLE_USER` an not only `USER` as a role.

Comment: Hi M. Deinum, I created all roles as ROLE_USER and ROLE_ADMIN but Spring puts my user in ROLE_ANONYMOUS I don't know why.

Comment: Because you probably aren't authenticated, you have custom filters and a user details manager so you probably are doing something wrong. You are also stateless so you have to make sure you are repopulating the context at each request. I suspect that is the task of the `StatelessAuthenticationFilter` and that isn't kicking in, however you haven't posted the code for that.